# Appium Server, on windows, is throwing error: Responding to client that we did not find a valid resource

Tags: java, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to run Appium Serve on my Windows 7 machine using a simple command:

D:\Appium\node.exe D:\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\Appium.js -g C:\Users\vdopia\AppData\Local\Temp\applog_12232015_110310.txt --no-reset

in command prompt, it shows that Appium is started.  When I browse the url `http://127.0.0.1:4723`, I get the message below in my command prompt and because of this I am not able initialize remotedriver also. Surprisingly, the same thing works well in MAC.

```
        Logs:
            > info: --> GET / {}
            > info: [debug] Responding to client that we did not find a valid resource
            > info: <-- GET / 404 0.712 ms - 47 
            > info: <-- GET /favicon.ico 200 0.535 ms - 1150 

I am pasting code here to start appium server, first I am writing command in a sh or bat file then executing the bat file.

    public static boolean startAppiumServer() 
        {       
            //Kill any Existing Appium Before Starting new session
            logger.info("Stopping any running instance of appium. ");
            try{SDKCommonUtils.killAppiumServer();}catch(Exception  e){}

            boolean flag = false;
            File logFile = null;
            String commandFile = null;

            if(System.getProperty("os.name").matches("^Windows.*"))
            {
                //Getting temp dir
                String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").toString();
                logFile = new File(tempDir+"\\applog"+"_"+MobileTestClass_Methods.DateTimeStamp()+".txt");

                commandFile = System.getenv("AUTOMATION_HOME").concat("\\tpt\\appium_commands.bat");

                String appiumCmdLocation_Windows = MobileTestClass_Methods.propertyConfigFile.getProperty("appiumCmdLocationForWindows").toString();

                String nodeExe = appiumCmdLocation_Windows.concat("\\node.exe");
                String appiumJs = appiumCmdLocation_Windows.concat("\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\Appium.js");

                String strText = "start /B " + nodeExe + "  " + appiumJs + " -g " + logFile.toString() + " --full-reset --command-timeout 60 ";
                FileLib.WriteTextInFile(commandFile, strText);
            }
            else
            {
                logFile = new File("/tmp/applog"+"_"+MobileTestClass_Methods.DateTimeStamp()+".txt");
                commandFile = System.getenv("AUTOMATION_HOME").concat("/tpt/appium_commands.sh");

                String strText = "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; /usr/local/bin/appium -g " + logFile.toString() + " --full-reset --command-timeout 60 " ;
                FileLib.WriteTextInFile(commandFile, strText);
            }

            try
            {
                logger.info("Executing Command File: "+ commandFile +" to start appium service. ");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandFile);

                /** wait until appium server is started */
                flag = waitForAppiumServer();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                flag = false;
                logger.error("There were some issues while executing command to launch appium service. ",e);
            }

            return flag;
        }
```

Comment: Did you attach device to machine?

Comment: Of course I attached the device.

Comment: Did you check by ADB command if it is showing device in list?

Comment: @HelpingHands : See the whole scenario is: If I run appium server UI then everything is fine, problem occurs when I start appium server by executing commands in command prompt in windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide server address then it will be used as `0.0.0.0` from command prompt in windows as

`info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723`.

Please provide  `--address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723` parameter from command line and try to use same address and port while initializing driver object in your script.

Comment: I am sorry this solution didn't work... it is trowing same error !!

Comment: Please post your code used to start a session, may be you are missing any capability

Comment: Yeah @Pankaj ! You have mentioned command to start a appium server , but i was expecting code which you have written for starting a new driver session.

Comment: I was expecting below code . Try with below capabilities if it works for you   File app = new File("apk-path.apk");
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"ur-version");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"your-deviceName");
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app);
  AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Comment: I already have these capabilities, still I get the same error: Responding to client that we did not find a valid resource. Repeating again: just after starting appium server, if you hit the url: http://127.0.0.1:4723, I get this response, the same error I received if I try to do anything using driver with above capability.